# Pyephem: Precession not being applied correctly in epoch calculation?

Tags: pyephem

I have very recently downloaded pyephem. I like the user interface a lot.

However, I am getting very flaky results from it, specifically when I try to obtain the estimates of a star's declination at some point in the past. I have used exactly the code associated with the Thuban/Polaris example described in http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/projects/pyephem-manual.html#FixedObjects,Precession,andEpochs and I get completely different results. I am wondering if there is something else that needs to be added to my script to make things work, or if there is a new bug in pyephem.

My script looks like this:

```
import ephem
import ephem.stars

polaris = ephem.readdb("Polaris,f|M|F7,2:31:48.704,89:15:50.72,2.02,2000")
polaris.compute()    

thuban = ephem.readdb("Thuban,f|V|A0,14:4:23.3,64:22:33,3.65,2000")
thuban.compute()

print 'my result for current polaris dec',polaris.dec
print 'webpage result                    89:15:50.73\n'

print 'my result for current thuban dec',thuban.dec
print 'webpage result                   64:22:32.99\n'

polaris.compute(epoch='-2800')
print 'my result for polaris dec in -2800',polaris.dec
print 'webpage result                     63:33:17.63\n'

thuban.compute(epoch='-2800')
print 'my result for thuban dec in -2800',thuban.dec
print 'webpage result                    89:54:34.97\n'
```

Running it produces the following output. I can understand why the first two comparisons are slightly different (the example on the web page was created in the recent past), but you can see that the declination did not change between the current date and epoch -2800 for either star, but in the example on the web page the declination changes a great deal for both stars between the two epochs:

```
my result for current polaris dec 89:19:19.5
webpage result                    89:15:50.73

my result for current thuban dec 64:18:39.5
webpage result                   64:22:32.99

my result for polaris dec in -2800 89:19:19.5
webpage result                     63:33:17.63

my result for thuban dec in -2800 64:18:39.5
webpage result                    89:54:34.97
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.dec` attribute is auto-adjusted in several ways that would have interfered with the tutorial's attempt to show how precession works, so — if you will look carefully at the tutorial's code — I think you will find that it always asks for the `.a_dec` the “astrometric declination” of Polaris and Thuban. If you will make this slight spelling correction to your own code above by adding `a_` to the front of the attribute name, then I think you will find that your printed answers agree with those printed in the tutorial!